# Django Rest Framework PrimaryKeyRelatedField clearing if not set

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer that inherits from `ModelSerializer` that looks something like this:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    set_favourite_books = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source="favourite_books", many=True, required=False, write_only=True)
    set_favourite_movies = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source="favourite_movies", many=True, required=False, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ('set_favourite_books', 'set_favourite_movies')
```

If I POST this it will work fine:

```
{ 
    'set_favourite_books': [1, 2, 3]
    'set_favourite_movies': [1, 2, 3]
}
```

However if I try to only update one of the fields (not posting the other field entirely) like below:

```
{ 
    'set_favourite_books': [1, 2, 3]
}
```

It will set the books, but clear the movies.

**How can I get it to maintain the movies if the `set_favourite_movies` field is not submitted at all?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DRF's default behavior for updating models to update all fields on `PUT` and only the provided fields on `PATCH` (see [`UpdateModelMixin`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L111-184) when you use `ModelViewSet`)is on `PUT` to update the complete object. If you want a partial update, use `PATCH` with only the fields you want to update.